# Kubernetes logs command TLS handshake timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am running the open source kube version 1.9, getting  TLS handshake timeout error while running the `kubectl logs` command, other `kubectl` commands are working fine.

```
#:/etc/kubernetes/pki> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app1-9         1/1       Running   0          2d

#:/etc/kubernetes/pki> kubectl logs counter
Error from server: Get https://XX.XX.XX.XXXX:10250/containerLogs/default/counter/count: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

kubectl version is:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T21:07:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T20:55:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I see the apiserver is running on 10250. How to make `kubectl` connect to apiserver over the SSL?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my cluster and it has been plagiung me for the past few months. I ran the command curl -v8 showed my it wasn't a tls/cert issue (really bad error message.)

This lead me to look at other issues, such as the API server/gateway, nodes and so forth. It turns out that the the error *--on my cluster--* was caused by **mismatch API's**. This was due to my adding a new node. After doing some digging I found a command that would allow me to see what API version/s my cluster was running and then guide me to an updated version.

I updated my cluster using '**kubeadm upgrade plan**'. The command advised I could update the cluster to version 10.1.5 or 10.1.11, however I would need to updated **Kubeadm** first. I updated Kubeadm and then updated my kube components on all the other nodes. Once the nodes had been updates, I used the *kubeadm init* join command to add all the nodes to the new cluster set. **NB** at this point I would like to say that none of my PODS dropped.

Everything had rejoined the cluster and now, I can browse the logs across the cluster through all PODS.

I hope this helps anyone who's looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I see the apiserver is running on 10250. How to make kubectl connect to apiserver over the SSL?

It's actually *not* the `apiserver` running on 10250, that's `kubelet`'s port on the Node upon which the `counter` Pod has been scheduled. When asking for the logs, the `apiserver` redirects `kubectl` over to the actual Node in order to stream the logs directly out of `kubelet` (rather than streaming the logs from kubelet through the apiserver down to you).

Experiencing a connection timeout smells very much like misconfigured security groups between your machine and the Node. I don't know off-hand if one can pin the kubelet port to a specific one, in order to statically whitelist it, but it seems like a problem someone would have experienced before.