# Kubectl logs returning tls handshake timeout

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

> kubectl -n namespace1 logs -f podname

returns the following error.

> Error from server: Get https://ipaddress:10250/containerLogs/namespace1/podname-xxkb9/podname?follow=true: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Proxies are unset.

> unset http_proxy
> unset https_proxy

But Still the issue comes.
Could anyone help me with this issue please.

Comment: Do other `kubectl` commands work?

Comment: yes kubectl get pods -n namespace are working @KamolHasan

Comment: how about `kubectl exec/attach/portforward....`?

Comment: kubectl logs only not working. @KamolHasan

Comment: @ManiGopal could you please post the result of the command `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl describe pod_name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Kubernetes without proxy resolved this issue.

Comment: What if it was production and reinstalling Kubernetes isn't a option?

Comment: Same issue here, won't work in production

Answer (score 3):

What I know for sure this is not a cert issue. This is API versions mismatching problem or something else related to API. There were a few discussions on stack in the past, I'll attach them in the end. Also, I experienced the same few years ago and at that time I also resolved this problem by `kubeadm upgrade`

First of all check real error message by running `kubectl logs -v9` for maximum verbosity level.

Most probably you checked other commands like `kubectl get pods, nodes`, etc. [None of those commands](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71343#issuecomment-441605440) require the apiserver to contact the kubelet, only kubectl logs does.
And @Kamos asked you absolutely the right question re: `exec/attach/portforward`. 99% they also doesn't work for you because they also require contacting kubelet directly.

There are a lot of chances you will fix issue with [Upgrading kubeadm clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/)

References:

**1.** [Kubernetes - net/http: TLS handshake timeout when fetching logs (BareMetal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302515/kubernetes-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-when-fetching-logs-baremetal)

**2.** [Kubernetes logs command TLS handshake timeout ANSWER1!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335149/9929015)

**3.** [Kubernetes logs command TLS handshake timeout ANSWER2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51357740/9929015)

**4.** [kubectl logs failed with error: net/http: TLS handshake timeout #71343](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71343)

Comment: There is also the possibility of some network problem between the worker node hosting the pod and the master node serving apiserver.

Comment: yes, could also be. logs will help a bit(at least should)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I experienced this with AWS EKS and kubectl running on WSL:
[image]

I put in my .bashrc:

```
# fixed issue with tls handshake error of terraform EKS
export NO_PROXY="${NO_PROXY};eks.amazonaws.com"
```

The issue then dissapeared.